# Strange behavior of keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro, mission-control

On my imac I have system Preferences -> hardware -> keyboard -> keyboard & text input set with a checkmark for move focus to menu bar with ^F2.  It works.

On my (pretty new) macbook air, I set the same thing, and it doesn't work.

I have (Text boxes and lists only ) checked on both machines, but I seem to get the same result with all controls checked..

Both are os x version 10.8.4

--

On the other hand, Under mission control, when switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application WORKS for macbook air, but not for the iMac.

What am I missing?  Anyone else have these kinds of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have this setting enabled?

[image]

If you don't, you can still use fn-control-F2 to move focus to the menu bar.